# Getting an AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'send_message' when I try to send a message with Telegram bot

Tags: python, api, bots, telegram, attributeerror

Im getting an AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'send_message' when I try to send a message.
And I know that 'Update' class does not have a 'send_message' attribute but Im not using the 'Update' class.
Im using the 'bot' class but Im still getting the same exact error.

Here is my code:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
from telegram import Bot

bot = Bot(token='TOKEN')

def start(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Hello")


updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
command_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(command_handler)

updater.start_polling()
```

Here is the error;

```
bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Hello")
AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

Tried to import the Bot library separately but still nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working! You need to add a `context` parameter instead of an `update` parameter

Here is the updated code:

```
def start(bot, context):
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Hello")

start_handler = CommandHandler("start", start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
```